# vscode fails to resolve dependencies declared in a maven profile

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with vscode and a maven project in which some dependencies are declared for a specific profile as follows:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            ...
```

When I open this project in visual studio code, the compilation fail because the dependencies declared for this profile (e.g "dev") cannot be resolved.

Notes:

- I have this problem only in vscode. When I lunch the compilation with maven command or in Eclipse IDE (specifying the maven profile to use), it's ok.
- I have this problem only for the dependencies declared for a profile (for all other dependencies declared in the global "dependencies" section it's OK)
- the "Java Extension Pack" and "Maven for java" extensions are installed, and the version of vscode is 1.36.1
- for "Maven for java" extension, I tell it to always use the "dev" profile whit this settings: "maven.executable.options": "-Pdev"

How can I make vscode to load the dependencies of my maven "dev" profile?

Comment: Do you have a `<dependencyManagement>` section in (one of) your POM(s) that contains `spring-boot-starter-undertow` with the intended version? Remember, [GAV](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) is needed to identify an artifact.

Comment: @GeroldBroser, yes, in the <dependencyManagement> section, I have a pom dependency in wihch the version of all my dependencies are specified. It seems  top be a problem with vscode (settings) and not the pom declaration because the compilation is ok when I lunch it from maven command.

Comment: you could refer to this:https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/117,it maybe could help you

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/117